# Special case of prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions 4k+1

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

In terms of the proof of prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions, I have seen many proofs involving with the concept of "character". Is there an alternative way (without such a concept) to show that the number of primes which are congruent to 1 modulo 4 is asymptotic to $\dfrac{x}{2\log x}$?

Comment: In this case, the "character" involved is the function on odd integers defined by $f(n) = (-1)^{(n-1)/2}$. One certainly doesn't need to understand characters in general to establish the mod-4 case of the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions. But of course the standard proof remains the same whether or not this function is called a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that

$$ \frac{\#(\text{primes}~~ qn+a \leq x)}{\pi(x)/\phi(q)}\to 1~ \text{as} ~ x\to \infty, $$

that there are roughly the same number of primes in each residue class $a$ if $(a,q)=1$ without some version of Dirichlet characters/series might be hard.

There is no special virtue of using $Li(x)$ here, any function $\sim \pi(x)$ will work.

Hadamard and de La Vallée Poussin are credited with the first proof of this. The most economical proof I can find is that in G.J.O. Jameson's *The Prime Number Theorem* at pages 175-176. It depends on the sorts of calculations you specifically ask to avoid.

In light of comments it seems like a tall order.

Edit: Regarding the hint in the comment about points on the circle $a^2+b^2=c^2$ I remembered some theorems that are in the linked paper. The main idea is that for primitive Pythagorean triples (a,b,c), c is always of the form $4n+1.$  Assuming all primes of this form occur in the sequence of primitive triples I do not see how to show that their cardinality is $\sim$ the cardinality of primes $4n+3.$ If the idea is showing that the cardinality of primes c is 1/4 of numbers generally I don't see that either.

Comment: My professor gave me a hint by using the number of lattice points on the circle $a^2 + b^2 = n$. In other words, defining $l(n) = \#\dfrac{1}{4} \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : a^2 + b^2 =n\}$ is very helpful. However, I cannot see how it is related to my problem.

Comment: @user110706: your prof may have been thinking of ideas like those at p. 58 of the linked paper. Whether those get you all the way to a proof w/o Dirichlet characters or the equivalent I am not yet sure. http://www2.math.uu.se/~lal/kompendier/Talteori.pdf

Comment: Hi Daniel. Could I ask you to show that a function is holomorphic? I have posted my question on this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098955/how-to-show-a-function-is-holomorphic. I am so sorry for bothering you like this. Cheers!

Comment: @user110706: it is no bother but the problem appears somewhat involved and my time's a little short. i can begin to think about it.

Comment: I am really appreciated for your help. Thanks a lot.